# how can I add an arbitrary matrix at the top of model-view stack in openGL?

Tags: opengl

I get the current matrix by

```
glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mtrx);
```

then I do something with the model-view matrix and finally I want "mtrx" back on the stack but I don't know how.
I can't use glLoadMatrixf(mtrx) because it replaces the top most stack but I don't want the content of the stack to be lost.

Comment: Where are you reading that [`glLoadMatrix()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml) clears the matrix stack?  Because it just replaces the *topmost* stack entry, not the entire stack.

Comment: thank, I edited my question. but the problem is still there :)

Answer (score 2):

`glPushMatrix()` followed by `glLoadMatrix()`.